# How to Store User Provided Tabular Data?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to allow users to upload tabular data (rows and columns of data). I have no idea what this table will look like (no clue about the number of rows and columns). Without using EAV, is there a way I can just store all this data in one massive table?

If I say that 100 columns is the maximum allowed columns for this user uploaded data, then I just create a table with 100 columns. When user uploads their data, I just fit it in this massive table.

I guess the problem would also be how to store the user's column header. And trying to do so might mean I have some form of EAV anyway.

I'm specifically looking at non-EAV solutions.

Suggestions?

Comment: What do you have to do with this data? Do you need to support any queries? What about data types? Is everything a string?

Comment: Everything will be string. I will need to do some queries and I *think* when I query, I will need to know the column names of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use real MySQL tables. If you know the column names when you get the data you could make up a suitable table name (make sure you make these up yourself), create the table with the necessary number of `varchar` columns and populate it. You'd want to quote the column names all the time of course, that way you wouldn't have to worry too much about what the columns are called. You would also want to pay attention to the sizes of the incoming columns.

You could always ask the database for the table's schema if you needed it, just talk to the [information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html) tables or from [`show columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html) queries.

You might want to set aside a database (or one database per client) for these user defined tables.

Comment: So if a 1000 different users upload a table, I would create 1000 new tables in my database?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: If you're going to have a lot of them then you could partition them into separate databases to keep the numbers down. I'm not sure if MySQL has any per-database limits on the number of tables or if it cares if there are a lot of tables in a single database. There's always MongoDB or other document databases if they fit your needs.

Comment: The application is currently in MySQL. I do not want to introduce another platform.

Comment: If you don't use real tables then you'd end up with a huge table with a couple hundred columns and then another EAVish table that holds the mapping from the pseudo-table column names to the real column names. That may work for you, or maybe not.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if it will work. Suggestions how to model this concept?

Comment: The huge "one table to bind them" approach? You'd need a separate three column mapping table for the "real" names: (virtual_table_id, real_column_name, column_number) or something like that. Then when you need the names, just pull them out run things through the resultant `real_column_name -> column_number` mapping.